# how to pass a function with parameters as a parameter?

Tags: bash, shell

There are two shell functions like belows

```sh
function call_function {
    func=$1
    desc=$2
    log_file=$3

    $func >> ${log_file} 2>&1
    ...
}

function echo_str {
   str=$1
   echo "$str"
}
```

How can I pass a shell function with parameters as a parameter?

I tried this:

```sh
call_function $( echo_str "test" ) "Echoing something" /var/logs/my_log.log
```

but only got

```
command not found
```

I googled it but nothing helps.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `echo $func >> ${log_file} 2>&1` should fix the error.

Comment: Note that `function` isn't valid sh syntax; it's a ksh extension supported also by bash. Having `sh` in the title and `bash` in the tagging is thus a bit confusing.

Comment: See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete, which mentions `function` twice (once in table 1, and again in table 3).

Comment: None of the shells have first-class functions, so you are probably doing to be happier switching to a language that does.

Comment: Is the error message really just "command not found"?  Usually, there is a prefix on that string, something like "-bash: foo: command not found".  Are you seeing "-bash: ...: command not found"?

Comment: @chepner, ...I've done a lot of functional programming in bash, particularly in an ex-job where I assembled a suite of execline-style tools. It's no LISP, but that doesn't mean one can't apply FP tools to great benefit.

Comment: If it came out as just `: command not found`, I wonder if the file was saved with DOS newlines, sending the cursor back to the left when printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this right, reorder your arguments to put the function to call *last*, and use `shift` to pop off the other arguments -- which will leave the function to call *and its arguments* in the `"$@"` array.

```
call_function() {
    local log_file desc
    log_file=$1; shift || return
    desc=$1; shift || return
    "$@" >>"$log_file" 2>&1
}

echo_str() {
    local str
    str=$1
    echo "$str"
}

#             log_file   desc                           func     args
call_function myfile.log "a function to echo something" echo_str "string to echo"
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
call_function $( echo_str "test" ) "Echoing something" /var/logs/my_log.log
```

This `$( echo_str "test" )` call will execute `echo_str "test"` which will result in `test`, so `call_function` will execute:

```
test >> /var/logs/my_log.log 2>&1
```

So, you either create a dedicated function to log messages easily to a log file:

```sh
log_msg() {
    current_date=$(date -u)
    echo "[$current_date] $1" >> $2
}
```

or change `call_function` as suggested by @Darkman

Comment: Could you show how this answer would work when the OP wants to pass arguments to `test`?

Comment: I only tried to show him why his example of "test" failed.